# Missing version number while creating bower.json

Tags: javascript, json, npm, bower

While I created the bower.json file, I did not get the version number in the command line questionnaire. This is the result:

```
{
    "Name": "conFusion",
    "Authors": [
        "Aurora"
    ],
    ...
}
```

How ever, the version number was not asked? How can I manually add it to the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the `bower.json` file and add a field `version` with the its value.

Note that it should respect the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)

```
{
    "name": "conFusion",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "authors": [
        "Aurora"
    ],
    ...
}
```